# tikz intersection fails in combination with the library calc

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

In the second example I am trying to work the the library `intersection`. It works fine as long as I don't use the `calc` library.

The first example shows my intention. I am using `($2*(w1')$)` which produces the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (F') at (-0.8,-0.1);
\coordinate (F'') at (0.8,0);
\draw[thick](O) ++(F') ++ (F'');
\draw[gray,name path=circle around F'] (F') circle (1.2);
\draw[gray,name path=circle around F''] (F'') circle (1.2);
\draw[name intersections={of=circle around F' and circle around F'',by={w1,w1'}}]   (intersection-1) node[dot,draw]{}
-- (intersection-2)node[dot,draw]{};
\draw[red,thick] (w1) -- (w1');
\draw[blue,thick] (w1) -- ($2*(w1')$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the picture you can see that the blue line is expanded.

[image]

In the second (not minimal) example it fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,thick,fill,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
\coordinate (B) at (-1,0);\node[dot] at (B) {};\node[left] at (B) {$B$};
\coordinate (D) at (0,1);\node[dot] at (D) {};\node[anchor=south east] at (D) {$D$};
\coordinate (F) at (0,-.25);\node[dot] at (F) {};\node[anchor=west] at (F) {$F$};

\draw[thick,name path=line FB] (F) -- (B);
\draw[thick,name path=line FD] (F) -- (D);
\draw[gray,name path=circle around F] (F) circle (0.8);

\path[name intersections={of=circle around F and line FB,by=F'}];
\path[name intersections={of=circle around F and line FD,by=F''}];

\draw[gray,name path=circle around F'] (F') circle (0.6);
\draw[gray,name path=circle around F''] (F'') circle (0.6);
\draw[name intersections={of=circle around F' and circle around F'',by={w1,w1'}}] 
   (w1) node[dot]{}
-- (w1')node[dot]{};
\draw[red] (w1') -- ($2*(w1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The red line misses the intersection. I don't know why.

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: I can get the result with `\draw[red] (w1') -- ($(w1')!2!(w1)$);`. So probably `calc` library is assuming something different for the omitted coordinate in `($coord1!2!coord2$)` type of input.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks for your comment. This input method I didn't try.

Comment: If TikZ is deep magic, the `calc` library is the deeper magic from beyond the dawn of time.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Sounds really obscure ;-). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Incidentally, I didn't know that this sort of syntax was allowed in TikZ calc so I've learnt something too.  Good question.

Comment: @AndrewStacey It also doesn't work on the first example if you change the radii and the centers significant enough. I guess it's better not use it unless the origin is explicitly the omitted coordinate.

Comment: @percusse I didn't try the first example, but in the second then `k*(coord)` gave the point `k` times in the direction of `(coord)` **on the line through the origin**, which is what it *ought* to do (mathematically).

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Not only ought

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coordinate `($2*(w1)$)` means "take the coordinate represented by `(w1)` and double it".  Traditionally, we scale vectors from the origin.  If you draw blobs at the origin, `(w1)` and `($2*(w1)$)` then you will see that they line up on a straight line.

What you want is "take the vector from `(w1')` to `(w1)`, double it, and anchor it back at `(w1')` again".  You can do this with `($(w1') + 2*(w1) - 2*(w1')$)` (parentheses seem to confuse it a little) or `($(w1')!2!(w1)$)`.

Comment: Experimenting shows that when I try to use parentheses then it thinks they are specifying coordinates so can't be used for mathematical grouping.

Comment: For grouping you can use `{}` An example is shown in the manual ;-)

Comment: `$(w1') + 2*{(w1') - (w1)}$` makes my machine hang.  Where's the example?

Comment: I meant this example `\fill [black] (${3*(4-3)}*(1,0.5)$) circle (2pt);` page 120.